# How do I get the object from my api to display the api content on the page?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

Currently, my application is able to get the data from my API. However, I am having trouble iterating over the data so I can display it via state. I keep getting the following error message in the console: getSoups failed TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

It is referencing the following code:

```
getSoups() {
    axios
        .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/soups/')
        .then(response => {
            console.log('soup response data', response);
            response.data.soups.map(soup => ({
                id: soup.id,
                title: soup.title,
                name: soup.name,
                description: soup.description,
                front_thumb_img_url: soup.front_thumb_img_url
            }))
        })
        .then(soups => {
            this.setState({
                soups
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('getSoups failed', error);
    });
}
```

The whole component: menu-container.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import Soups from './soups-edited';

export default class MenuContainer extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            soups: []
        };

        this.getSoups = this.getSoups.bind(this);
    }

    getSoups() {
        axios
            .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/soups/')
            .then(response => {
                console.log('soup response data', response.data.soups);
                response.data.soups.map(soup => ({
                    id: soup.id,
                    title: soup.title,
                    name: soup.name,
                    description: soup.description,
                    front_thumb_img_url: soup.front_thumb_img_url
                }))
            })
            .then(soups => {
                this.setState({
                    soups
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('getSoups failed', error);
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getSoups();
    }

    render() {
        const { soups } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className='soups'>
              { soups.map(soup => {
                  const { id, title, name, description,front_thumb_img_url } = soup;
                  return (
                      <ul key={id}>
                          <li>{title}</li>
                          <li>{name}</li>
                          <li>{description}</li>
                          <li>{front_thumb_img_url}</li>
                      </ul>
                  )
              })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the Component where you are showing the result? You'd better do the mapping in the component itself.

Comment: Try to `console.log(response.data.soups)` and see if it is even defined.

Comment: @randomboiguyhere When I just console.log(response) it shows the objects. But with console.log(response.data.soups) it is undefined.

Comment: @JohnGartsu then why use the `.soups`? Can't you just use `response.map()`?

Comment: I imagine the `.soups` portion is undefined. Two things I would try: `console.log(response.data)` initially. Inspect that and verify there is a property of that JSON object called `soups`. If not, there's your answer.

Comment: @CyberMessiah I have added the full component.

Comment: If I were you I would just pass the main parent object in the state and then do the mapping in the component. Thus it will be easier to trace any errors. Just return     this.setState({ soups: response.data }); instead of the mapping in the getSoups(). I guess this is causing troubles.

Comment: @ShaneCreedon when I console.log(response.data) it return an array of soup response data (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]. How do I make it so it a json object with axios?

Comment: @CyberMessiah Thank you, will try that, and let you know.

Comment: @randomboiguyhere wouldnt I have to do response.data.map(). or would i just map over response ?

Comment: @JohnGartsu Well since you are using axios, you would need to do `response.data.map()`

Comment: @JohnGartsu But better do that in a component and then see what will come from the console.log / when you put <li> with the appropriate values.

Comment: @CyberMessiah your solution worked! The data is now being displayed. That allowed state to take in the new array of objects. Thank you!

Comment: I will add the answer so that you can accept it, if you don't mind. May be useful for somebody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would just pass the main parent object (array of objects) in the state and then do the mapping in the component. Thus it will be easier to trace any errors. Just return

```
 this.setState({ soups: response.data });
```

instead of the mapping in the getSoups(). I guess this is causing troubles. In short transfer the logic(mapping) to the component to better see what the outcome is.

Comment: Here is a copy of the solution to referenced code:                                                
```getSoups() {
        axios
            .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/soups/')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    soups: response.data
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('getSoups failed', error);
        });
    } ```

Answer (score 0):

When you console.log `response.data` you get an array of soup objects. So therefore, by excluding the `.soups` property from your response query, you were able to get the data. This is because the data you're returning from the controller did not provide an object with the `soups` property.

So, you can just map through your response like so:

```js
response.data.map((item) => {
     console.log(item);
 })
```

Alternatively, if you want to have the `.soups` property in your json response, then you need to return a response entity that has this mapping. You can do this via returning an object or via returning a hashmap containing the soups array with a key of "soups".

I hope this is of some help.